# How to focus on a window with python?

Tags: python, web, web-scraping, pyautogui

I'm writing a python code that allows a user to mark text from a website and then paste it into a word document. I'm using pyautogui and win32clipboard.

**So here is the flow-**
1. the user finds an interesting line on a website.
2. the user marks the desired text.
3. the user runs the python script ( I don't want python to run all the time, only when asked).
4. python uses pyautogui to copy the text (ctrl + c) and then win32clipboard.
5. python writes the copied text to a doc file.

As for now, the only problem I have is in the transition from 3 to 4.
The issues are-

a) when I try to run the python from cmd, ctrl c hotkey makes the script stop (keyboard interrupt). How can I overcome that?

b) how can I make the script run on the current website? how do I return the focus to that window? as for now, I'm running the script within Pycharm and it works, but I want it to run in the "outside world"!

Thanks in advance,
Karin :-)

P.S- this is the code I'm trying to run.

```
--getting the url

pyautogui.hotkey("Ctrl","f")
time.sleep(.01)
pyautogui.hotkey("Ctrl","c")
time.sleep(.01)
win32clipboard.OpenClipboard()
url = win32clipboard.GetClipboardData()
win32clipboard.CloseClipboard()

--- getting the marked text

pyautogui.hotkey("Ctrl","c")
time.sleep(.01)
win32clipboard.OpenClipboard()
text = win32clipboard.GetClipboardData()
win32clipboard.CloseClipboard()
```

Comment: Can we see your code so far?

Comment: This is the part where I get the url-
        pyautogui.hotkey("Ctrl","f")
        time.sleep(.01)
        pyautogui.hotkey("Ctrl","c")
        time.sleep(.01)
        win32clipboard.OpenClipboard()
        url = win32clipboard.GetClipboardData()
        win32clipboard.CloseClipboard()

This is how I get the marked text-
    pyautogui.hotkey("Ctrl","c")
    time.sleep(.01)
    win32clipboard.OpenClipboard()
    text = win32clipboard.GetClipboardData()
    win32clipboard.CloseClipboard()

Comment: Because I'm running it inside Pycharm I use Ctrl + f instead of Ctrl + l (tha'ts how i simulate the url line in Pycharm).

Comment: I'd really appreciate some help guys :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after a lot of research, I found a very simple solution for the problem- using time.sleep(). During that time the user can switch to the desired window and the code works fine :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use
pyautogui.hotkey("alt","tab") time.sleep(.1)

Answer (score -1):

To focus on window (make it active), you may use:

```
import pyautogui
...
w = pyautogui.getActiveWindow()
# or
w = pyautogui.getWindowsWithTitle("Chrome")[0]

w.activate()
```